# Java closes(crashes) when calling JNI from a GUI but not from a console app

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface

I have a java application (1.7 64bit) that I am having call a c dll I compiled using cygwin via JNI. The c dll calls back to Java to pass some values to a method. All this seems to work except that after the JNI call returns a few seconds later the java program closes. But if i have the program run as a terminal program (no UI) it runs fine. if it matters when called from the UI its called from a button click. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

**Error reported from GUI:**

```
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) on project My Proj: Command execution failed. Process exited with an error: -1073741819 (Exit value: -1073741819) -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following    articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

**c function**

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_accessory_myaccessory_jni_dll_cfunction(JNIEnv *env, jclass class, jlong a, jobject b, jdouble c, jdouble d, jchar e, jchar f, jobject g) {

    return 0;
}
```

**java code**

```
long a= 0;
MyClass1 b= new MyClass1();
double c = 1;
double d = 0;
char e = 0;
char f = 0;
MyClass2 g= new MyClass2();
int r = dll.cFuction(a, b, c, d, e, f, g);
System.out.println("ret = " + r);
```

**java code**

```
public class dll {

    static {
        System.load("C:/development/mydll/dist/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/my.dll");
    }

    public static native int cFunction(long a, MyClass1 b, double c, double d,char e, char f, MyClass2 g);
}
```

**Additional note:**
Even if i remove ALL code from my jni method in c and just return 0 i get the same behavior

Answer (score 0):

As a test, try jumping off the event thread by launching a new thread
to make the call into native code.  If you still see failures, there
could be something else going on to cause the problem besides the difference 
in GUI vs non-GUI.  Disclaimer: This is not a perm fix but rather a P/D action.

```
badButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent arg0) {
      final Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            callNativeCode();
        }
      });
      t.setDaemon(true);
      t.start();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Java42. I had already tried that with the same results. The only thing I didnt do that you suggest is t.setDaemon(true). Not sure if that will make a difference. When I have a min I will try but in the mean time I have moved to compiling the c as a exe and using it as an external process.

Comment: @KevinG - If the separate thread did not change symptoms, setDaemon(true) will not fix anything.  It is only there to prevent potential hangs during JVM shutdown.